# Why Bind.ap is implemented by Bind.bind in Scalaz 7

Tags: scala, monads, typeclass, scalaz

I'm studying Scalaz 7, the type class system is so abstract, and one thing I can not understand is that why `Bind.ap` is implemented by `bind` in such a way.

```
trait Apply[F[_]] extends Functor[F] { self =>
  def ap[A,B](fa: => F[A])(f: => F[A => B]): F[B]
....
}


trait Bind[F[_]] extends Apply[F] { self =>
  /** Equivalent to `join(map(fa)(f))`. */
  def bind[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]

  override def ap[A, B](fa: => F[A])(f: => F[A => B]): F[B] = bind(f)(f => map(fa)(f))
  ....
}
```

I know we can treat `F[A => B]` as `F[C]`, so first argument of `bind` make sense, but the second argument requires a `A => F[B]`, how is `f => map(fa)(f)` equivalent to `A => F[B]` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know we can treat `F[A => B]` as `F[C]`

So `C` is `A => B`. Let's call that *fact 1*.

Let's rewrite `bind` with replacing A with C and B with D, so that we don't get confused by colliding type parameter variables:

```
def bind[C, D](fc: F[C])(f: C => F[D]): F[D]
```

So the `f` argument in the second parameter list of `bind` has to be of type `C => F[D]`, which can be written `(A => B) => F[D]` (using *fact 1*). Note that it's sneaky how in `bind(f)(f => ...)`, the second `f` is just a lambda parameter (which happens to be a function), while the first `f` is not a function. It could have been written `bind(f)(fun => map(fa)(fun))`.

> how is `f => map(fa)(f)` equivalent to `A => F[B]`??

Well, it is not... `f => map(fa)(f)` has to be typed as `(A => B) => F[D]`. So

- `f` is of type `A => B`
- `fa` is of type `F[A]`, that is the `fa` in the first parameter list of `ap` - not bind
- Looking at the definition of [map](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/v7.0.3/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Functor.scala#L20), `map(fa)(f)` will be of type `F[B]`

Which means that

```
 (A => B) =>   F[D]
    f     =>  map(fa)(f)
 (A => B) =>   F[B]
 // D is really B
```

So `bind(f)(f => map(fa)(f))` is of type `F[B]` which is what is required for `ap`...

May be this makes it clearer, conceptually, this is what is going on:

```
def ap[A, B](m_elem: => F[A])(m_fun: => F[A => B]): F[B] =
  for {
    fun <- m_fun
    elem <- m_elem
  } yield {
    fun(elem)
  }
//To hammer it home, same as: m_fun.flatMap(fun => m_elem.map(elem => fun(elem)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. The most confusing part is the name of the second argument of `bind(f)(f => map(fa)(f))`, should change to `bind(f)(g => map(fa)(g))`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the `bind` method signature, it's just a pretentious Haskell's way of naming `flatMap` function. So `Bind` trait provides an essential `flatMap` for a `Monad`.

Maybe it would be simpler to understand if we take `List[Int => String]` instead of `F[A => B]`, so what `bind` is doing it takes each function from the list, let's say we have the following list: `List((x: Int) => (x + 1).toString)` as `f` argument and `List(1,2)` as `fa` argument to `ap` method, and apply each function from `f` argument (`List` of `Int => String` functions) to each value of `fa` argument (`List` of `Int`).

So the answer on **how is f => map(fa)(f) equivalent to A => F[B]**, `A` in this code is a `Int => String` function from `f` `List` and when you map some value from `fa` `List` you get `F[B]`, which would be of type `String`